# add browser pane to Atom

Tags: atom-editor, elm

how can I add a browser window to Atom, and have it point to `localhost:8000` which is the location of my development server

```
------------------------------------------
|                   |                    |
|                   |                    |
|                   |                    |
|       CODE        |     DISPLAY        |
|                   |                    |
|                   |                    |
|___________________|____________________|
```

The nice part of this approach is that it's language agnostic.  In my case I am trying to run [elm-reactor](http://elm-lang.org/blog/time-travel-made-easy) without using Chrome. But it doesn't matter since I'm using localhost.  Until then, I will clumsily arrange Chrome and atom on my screen.

Atom is "hackable so I thought maybe it's been done already.  I'll put the Elm tag on in case someone chimes in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[atom-browser-webview](https://www.npmjs.com/package/atom-browser-webview) works well as a paned browser and it doesn't render as iframes like other browser panes have done. Here's a screenshot with `elm-reactor` running on port 8000.

[image: atom-browser-webview running elm-reactor]